# Bibliography style in springer template

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

I am using the [overleaf springer template](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines) and I want to include the bibliography style like IEEE template. On IEEE template i use like this:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\title{Dumb Title}

\author{
Blind review.
}

\maketitle

\input{Documents/1_AAAA}
\input{Documents/2_BBBB}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Documents/7_Bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

How should I use the `bibliographystyle` in the springer template to include my `.bib` file with my references?

NOTE: On the [original template](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines) references are not saved in a `.bib` file.

Comment: There is more than one "Springer template" -- and hence more than one bibliography style. Please clarify which one you intend to employ.

Comment: I'm using the Springer CCIS Format, and basically what I need is that my bibliographystyle shows the references like this template (the template link is on the original post).

Comment: There is a commented-out example of using a .bib file within the Springer template. It should be sufficient to delete/comment the manual `thebibliography` environment, uncomment the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` macros, and replace their arguments with your IEEEtran style and the name of your .bib file, respectively.

Comment: If you download and open the zip file `llncs2e.zip`, you'll find the following bib style file: `splncs04.bst`. Unless Springer is trying everyone who's made it this far, I think it's fair to assume that you should be using this bib style -- along with the `llncs` document class.